# How do I display one (1) plotSymbol in a scatter plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Environment: iOS 5.1
Scenario: 1-2  scatter/linear plots without any symbols.

I need to display only one (1) symbol where the user had touched upon a scatter plot.
The rest of the plot doesn't have any symbols.

I understand a symbol represents a data point.
But I need to graph all the data points... just set one (1) point/index to display its symbol per user-touch; hopefully to toggle on/off.

Regards,
Ric.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. Return a plot symbol for the index that you want highlighted and `[NSNull null]` for the others. Call `-reloadData` on the plot when you need to change the highlighted index.